# "With" clause not working over parent properties - hql join conditions

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have the next model:

```
abstract class Property {
    Boolean active = true
}

class Building extends Property {
    Integer id
    String name 
    static hasMany = [floors: Floor]
}

class Floor extends Property {
    Integer id
    String name
    static belongsTo = [building: Building]
}
```

I want to get all buildings with or without floors...
If I query those tables like so...

```
session.executeQuery("select b.name, b.active, f.name, f.active from Building b left outer join b.floors f")
```

I'll get the next query:

```
select
    building0_.name as col_0_0_,
    building0_1_.active as col_0_1_,
    floors1_.name as col_1_0_,
    floors1_1_.active as col_1_1_ 
from
    building building0_ 
inner join
    property building0_1_ 
        on building0_.id=building0_1_.id 
left outer join
    floor floors1_ 
        on building0_.id=floors1_.building_id 
left outer join
    property floors1_1_ 
        on floors1_.id=floors1_1_.id
```

Now I want to filter those floors which are active, so I did something like this:

```
session.executeQuery("select b.name, f.name from Building b left outer join b.floors f with(f.active = true)")
```

Since I need all buildings with or without floors if I put this filter in the where clause I'll be skipping those who has "active" in false and also those buildings that doesn't have any floor.

So I get the next error:

```
with clause can only reference columns in the driving table
```

Question is, how I should write the query to filter over Property.active?

I'm using grails version 2.5.2 and hibernate4 version 6.0.4

Comment: Silly question: can you just substitute `where (f.active = true)`?  What would Bruce Campbell do?

Comment: If I use "where" I'll get only those buildings with active floors and I need to get all buildings with active and inactive floors or buildings without floors

Comment: I'm filtering those floors that are active, thing is "active = false" means that a floor was logical deleted, I have a controller that should return a building with a list of all floors names, but if a building has no floors or just one floor deleted I still need to return the building

Comment: If I remove the active filter, the controller will return that "deleted" floor and that is wrong, and if I put the restriction in the where clause the controller will return only those buildings with active floors

Comment: Perhaps someone else can suggest a way to do this in a single query, but in my opinion this is likely one of those times where two or three simple queries are better (easier, clearer, and more maintainable) than one complex one.  I would write one to get buildings with no floors, one to get buildings with only inactive floors (could combine with previous if you really want to), and one to get buildings and floors where the floors are active.